# Adding Elements to an Already Existing Graph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a question about how to add elements to an already existing graph in Neo4j.

First, I have created nodes and relationships using the following query:

```
CALL apoc.import.csv(
    [{fileName: "file:///accounts.csv", labels:["Account"]}],
    [{fileName: "file:///transactions.csv", type:"transaction"}],
    {ignoreDuplicateNodes: true}
)
```

where the contents of `accounts.csv` and `transactions.csv` are as follows:

###### accounts.csv

```
acct_id:ID
"3240"
"6399"
"4771"
"2066"
```

###### transactions.csv

```
id,from_acct:START_ID,to_acct:END_ID,timestamp
221214,6399,3240,2022-12-15
221223,4771,3240,2022-12-23
221229,2066,3240,2022-12-29
```

So far, I have been able to create graphs without any problems.

Next, I tried to read the data from `add.csv` one row at a time and add nodes and relationships to the graph created by the above query, but I failed. The contents of `add.csv` are as follows:

###### add.csv

```
id,from_acct:START_ID,to_acct:END_ID,timestamp
221243,1000,3240,2023-1-1
221247,3000,3241,2023-1-2
```

For `add.csv` data, I only want to create nodes that do not yet exist. All relationships should be created, however.

In other words, in the first line, the node with `acct_id:3240` already exists, so I would like to add only the node with `acct_id:1000` to the graph and create a relationship with the node with `acct_id:3240`. In the second line, the node with `acct_id:3000` and the node with `acct_id:3241` both do not exist, so I would like to add both of them as new nodes and create a relationship with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It seems](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1048) the ability to avoid creating duplicates of existing nodes was discussed but not implemented for `apoc.import.csv`, because it would slow down the procedure. That procedure is really intended for loading a new database.

As an alternative, you could just do the import using [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) and [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/). `MERGE` is used in this query to only create the node if it does not yet exist:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///add.csv' AS row
MERGE (a1:Account {id: row[1]})
MERGE (a2:Account {id: row[2]})
CREATE (a1)-[:transaction {id: row[0], timestamp: row[3]}]->(a2)
```

NOTE: You can speed this query up by create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) on `:Account(id)`. Also, you should probably remove the first row (the header) from your data file, as the above query assumes it is not there.

Comment: Dear cybersam
Thank you very much for your advice. I have modified the query according to your advice and it works fine. I will try to learn how to use "index".
Your advice is always accurate and precise, and I greatly appreciate it. I am looking forward to your continued guidance in the future.